# read part text from a large file  as a page  by python

Tags: python, file, line

in python, file.readlines() get all line, it's waste if file size is large(several Mb). is there a efficient  way to get parts of files as page?
usually the part text display as a page in webapp, consider text are to be further decorated.

Comment: What do you mean by "page"?  You seem to be talking about reading a plain text file, but text files don't have pages.

Comment: You can easily read a set number of lines: `f = open(fname, 'r'); lines = [next(f) for i in range(100)]`

Comment: Why not just read the file one line at a time? Using `for line in f:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently i though of a rough way by byte size:

```
import os
def getpage(fname, pageindex, pagesize=100, ahead=20):
    """read page roughly by byte size"""
    size = os.path.getsize(fname)
    pagenum = size/pagesize
    f=open(fname,'r')
    pos=pageindex * pagesize
    #ahead some line
    pos -= ahead
    if pos <0: 
        pos = 0
    f.seek(pos)
    f.readline()
    txt = f.read(pagesize)
    txt += f.readline()    
    return txt
```

it's not fixed lines, some text are loose, some tight. but for moderate pagesize, it's ok for user's view.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a very pythonic and efficent way using Generators:

```
def getPage(fileName, numberOfLinesInAPage):

    f = open(fileName)

    lines = (line.strip() for line in f)
    pageBuffer = []
    for lineNum, eachLine in enumerate(lines,1):
        pageBuffer.append(eachLine)
        if lineNum % numberOfLinesInAPage == 0:
            yield pageBuffer
            pageBuffer = []
    if pageBuffer:
        yield pageBuffer    
    f.close()   

for i in getPage('test.txt',100):
    print i
```

Comment: As written, this still reads the entire file into memory (`f.readlines()`; you could simply use `for line in f`), and doesn't yield the leftover lines at the end.

Comment: @whi: Tested the code with 10,000,000 lines of text. `for line in f` works a treat in terms of space. And, yes, readlines would read the entire file as a list, even though you use a generator expression around it.

Comment: You still need to yield the last lines (say you have a 150-line file, for example, and a 100-line page).

Comment: Yup. Thats true. But, this code just gives an idea of how to use generators. Anyways, edited further